# CARMAGEDDON RECORDING PLANS?

Tags: field-recording

So if anyone hasn't already heard, they are doing massive roadwork on the 405 freeway between the 10 and 101 freeways.  Has anyone figured out a way to record the destruction of one or all of the 3 bridges they are planning to dismantle?  Seems like it might be possible to hike to one of the various parks in the corridor by the skirball bridge.  Thoughts?

Comment: Oh man, that title is a tug at the old gamer nerd heart strings.

Comment: Great idea!!! Sadly, I'll be out of town - going to Portland, Sacramento and then San Francisco during that time.